# Java - Convert Time toString

Tags: java

How can i convert a time like: 13:10 to a String?

> private final Time myTime;

I have something like this for int to String:

```
result = Integer.toString(myInt);
```

Comment: "13:10" already is a String.

Comment: @laune `.substring(5)` here `5` refers to `beginIndex` so the output will be `:00`

Comment: What's the full type of the Time class? java.sql.Time? etc...

Comment: @Adam Yes its java.sql.Time. im using oracle SQL.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Thanks. I meant to write `myTime.toString().substring( 0, 5 )`  for using Time's own toString method and truncating ":ss".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify what I think you're asking....

You have a `java.sql.Time` instance, which you want to convert to a String, however the built in `toString()` displays seconds....

```
final Time myTime = new Time(123456789);
System.out.println(myTime); // no good for you, 11:17:36
```

I'd recommend using SimpleDataFormat. The .format() method expects a UNIX timestamp which can be retrieved from getTime() method of the Time instance

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
System.out.println(format.format(myTime.getTime())); // 11:17
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i also know why the toString wasn't working haha

Comment: I saw the type is VARCHAR2(6)?

Comment: Still best to use a formatter to ensure your output is independent of any underlying database column configuration....

Answer (score 0):

Are you want convert "13:10" string to a date string?

```
   final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        String date = simpleDateFormat.parse("13:10").toString;
    } catch (ParseException ingnored) { }
```

Comment: your hh Hour represent in am/pm (1-12).